# RStudio increase font size in a barplot graphic

Tags: r, graph, fonts, rstudio

I am running R withing RStudio (Windows 10 OS) and have used the barplot function to make a plot.

The default label size looks fine but I need to send the file through a conversion package for a journal and in the converted file the resulting axis labels are too small. Thus, I seek R to increase the font size of the labels in the hope that the converted file will have a larger font size for the labels.

The two bar plots below yield the same size label fonts. Thus, adding "cex.names = 3" to the second bar plot has no effect.

```
barplot(temp$somenumber,  
        xlab = "My X label", ylab = "My Y label")
barplot(temp$somenumber,  
        xlab = "My X label", ylab = "My Y label", cex.names = 3)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What labels do you need to make larger ? Bar labels ? Tick labels ? Axis labels ?

Comment: axis labels (xlab and ylab)

Comment: Try `cex.lab=3`

Comment: Marco, Thank you.

Comment: Please mark my answer as "accepted" if it helps you solve your problem. Or I will continue to help you if you still have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Use `cex.lab=2`. But you may need to set `mar` to **avoid**

[image]

You can see that there is not enough space for y lable.

From `?par`

> mar: A numerical vector of the form c(bottom, left, top, right) which gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on the four sides of the plot. The default is `c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1`.

```
old.par <- par(mar = c(5,8,4,2)+0.1)
barplot(VADeaths, xlab = "My X label", ylab = "My Y label", cex.lab = 2)

par(old.par)
```

After I set `mar[2]` to `8.1` instead of `4.1`, I can get

[image]

Good luck to you!